# How to restrict my subdomain so that anyone can only access static contents like image, CSS, JS?

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a domain and a subdomain pointing to the same site on the server. I want to use the subdomain so that it can only be used to access the static contents like image, CSS, JS. Right now anyone can access the main website using the subdomain.

Both the domains have common htaccess files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  =subdomain.example.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|swf)$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks